# Rails rendering template dynamically does not resolve stylesheets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm using an external API to send email in Rails, so need to write my own code to render templates into a string.

```
  def html_for_template(template_name)
    template_root = "app/views/emails"
    template_path = "#{template_root}/#{template_name}"

    haml = File.open(template_path).read
    html = Haml::Engine.new(haml).render
    content = ERB.new(html).result
  end
```

Template contents:

```
%html
  %head
    %meta{content: "text/html; charset=utf-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}
    %link{"data-turbolinks-track" => "true", href: "styles.css", media: "all", rel: "stylesheet"}
```

The problem is, the resulting string does not actually resolve the contents of styles.css, but just copies the literal string `<link>...</link>`, which is useless, as I need the actual CSS contents inside the resulting string.

I've also tried:

```
:css
  = MyApp::Application.assets["styles.css"].to_s.html_safe
```

But this yields the same result: `MyApp::Application.assets["styles.css"].to_s.html_safe` is copied verbatim and not actually resolved. `ApplicationController.render(template_path)` also yields the same exact thing.

How do I render a template into a string while resolving stylesheet contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a HAML filter like `:css` the stuff is treated as a string and you have to use `#{something}` to run ruby code.

```
:css
  #{MyApp::Application.assets["styles.css"].to_s.html_safe}
```

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. Thanks!